# Language translation in worklight adapter

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

How to provide the language translation in worklight adapter. The response from the worklight adapter should be based on the language selected in the android app. How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume then that the content available on the server is available in different languages.

As you send the request to the backend, you can supply with it an additional parameter - "language". This parameter can be checked for at your backend system and based on it, the appropriate content in the appropriate language will be send back in the response.